# Can't load html file in page via javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, browser-extension, kango-framework

I am using kango extensions for browser plugin development.
I am trying to load file (`simple.html`) content that is inside plugin folder to browser page.
But I am getting this issue:

> Denying load of
>   chrome-extension://gkjiilcoknmmdcdpkepaiocmfkchgmhk/simple.html.
>   Resources must be listed in the web_accessible_resources manifest key
>   in order to be loaded by pages outside the extension.send @
>   sandboxed-default-document-end.js:5 chrome-extension://invalid/ Failed
>   to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED

This is code for it:

```
$("body").load(kango.io.getResourceUrl("simple.html"));
```

Comment: Have you read this:
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources

Comment: Is it listed in `web_accessible_resources`?

Comment: The error seems to be very specific about what is wrong. Have you add simple.html to the manisfest ?

Comment: I am not sure what manifest is. In kango there is this file etension info (http://kangoextensions.com/docs/api-reference/KangoExtensionInfo.html).
@merlin2011 where I can find this `web_accessible_resources`?

Comment: It is inside the manifest file.

Comment: You were right I was missing that piece. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As per kango framework structure, resources must be placed in `common/res` directory.

> Create 'res' folder under src/common folder.

Add your html file into it and then access that file using `kango.io.getResourceUrl("res/simple.html");`

[Click here](http://kangoextensions.com/docs/api-reference/kango-io.html?highlight=res#kango.io.getResourceUrl) for more details.